# Dynamically fill a <td> with a control asp.net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I got this table:

```
*FormMaster is x wide*

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_seq_header" Text="Sequence Header: "/>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_seq_header"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lb_asm_instr" Text="Sequence Instructions: "/>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_asm_instr" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="15" style="resize:none"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>    
        </table>
```

How do I stretch the textbox in a td to fill the rest of the body of the formmaster that is x wide?

I've tried adding a div in each td with a textbox, applied 'style' to each textbox with "width:100%", adding a style="width:y%" and a style="width:x%" (x+y=100) for each td pair but nothing happens.

Comment: like HaukurHaf said `table {width:100%}` and for each textbox `style='width:100%; box-sizing:border-box;'` ... textbox will fill td

Comment: @nelek thanks! Didn't know about box-sizing. Instead I added a padding to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to have the table fill it's container.

Add 100% width to the table:

```
table { width:100%; }
```

Then, add widths to the textboxes.